# How to report multivariate linear regression results

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, data-visualization, adjustment

I want to evaluate association between two continuous variables. But in my data, there are confounding factors such as age, weight,...  I think that simple correlation analysis is not correct for this analysis, so I made multivariate linear regression analysis to adjust confounding factors and I found association between these two variables even after adjusting. My problem is how to report this results in a scientific publication? Which coefficient should I use, unstandardized(B=0.36, p:0.02)  or standardized (β=0.17, p:0.02) and more important how can I show this association with a graph with SPSS. Could a simple scatter plot can be enough for this?

Comment: Are you perhaps using *multiple* linear regression, not *multivariate?*